# hoofers club in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm pretty sure about the facts that I declared, which are the following:

```
hoof(tony).
hoof(tim).
hoof(ellen).


hoof(X) :- skier(X); climber(X).
not(likes(X, rain)) :- climber(X).
likes(X, snow) :- skier(X).

likes(tony, X) :- \+likes(ellen, X).
likes(ellen, X) :- \+likes(tony, X).
likes(tony, rain).
likes(tony, snow).
```

And when I try to query with `hoof(X), climber(X), \+skier(X).`, it returns with an error message of:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,climber/1),top_level/0)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Defining `not/1` is troublesome!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any clauses for `climber/1` and thus the predicate is unknown to the Prolog runtime. Hence the predicate existence error for your query. A possible solution is to declared predicates such as `skier/1` and `climber/1` as *dynamic*:

```
:- dynamic([climber/1, skier/1]).
```

This directive declares the predicates to the runtime, informing it that the predicates can be modified at runtime. This will make your query fail instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @LeeMerlas Simply add the directive at the top of your source file.

Comment: it works now, but it should output 'Ellen', but instead its outputting 'no'